# kenxjs - Reference one column to two columns

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

How to fix this code?
I want to reference `recordId` to ids colums in the `tickets` and `packages` tables.

```
createTable(`payments`, function(t){
        t.increments();
        t.integer('userId').references('id').inTable(`users`).unsigned().onDelete('cascade');
        t.integer('recordId')
        .references('id').inTable(`tickets`).unsigned().onDelete('cascade');
        t.integer('recordId')
        .references('id').inTable(`packages`).unsigned().onDelete('cascade');
        t.string('peyFro');
        t.string('gateway').notNullable();
        t.string('authority').notNullable();
        t.integer('amount').notNullable();
        t.string('status').notNullable();
        t.dateTime('createdAt').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [foreign](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-foreign) function:

```
t.integer('recordId').unsigned();
t.foreign('recordId','payment_ticket_fk').references('tickets.id').onDelete('cascade');
t.foreign('recordId','payment_package_fk').references('packages.id').onDelete('cascade');
```

Linking one FK column to multiple PKs seems like bad design (that might lead to bad data) though. Perhaps you could just have two different FK columns.

Comment: Get this error: ```migration failed with error: alter table `payments` add constraint `payments_recordid_foreign` foreign key (`recordId`) references `packages` (`id`) on delete cascade - ER_DUP_KEY: Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-23b6_1f'```

Comment: I've updated my answer to add a key name (just something I cooked up - you can use a more meaningful one if needed). Maybe the default-generated name duplicates. If this still doesn't work, you might have some constraint existing in your schema from earlier runs.